# Pandas dataframe merge issue

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am learning python and pandas via Wes McKinney's *Python for Data Analysis*. One of the examples in Chapter 2 is a merge of MovieLens data on movie_id that is not working.  I think the issue is that in ratings the movie_id is an int64 and in movies it is an object. The merge returns an empty data frame.

I have read some of the previous posts on pandas and automatic data type assignment and found the dtype in pandas.io.parsers.read_table documentation but cant get the type to change.

The original code:

```
mnames = ['movie_id', 'title', 'genres']
movies = pd.read_table('ch02/movielens/movies.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=mnames)
```

And what my research indicated what should work:

```
movies = pd.read_table('ch02/movielens/movies.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=mnames, dtype={'movie_id':np.int64})
```

Unfortunately, the type isn't changed and the merge still returns an empty set. I am running pandas 0.10.1

Comment: FWIW the book code works for me.  To rule out a since-fixed bug, could you confirm that you're running pandas 0.10.1?

Comment: In [83]:



    import pandas
    print "Pandas version: ", pandas.__version__
 
    Pandas version:  0.10.1

Comment: Strange, then.  My `movie_id` Series in the movies dataframe is `Name: movie_id, Length: 3883, dtype: int64`, which seems right, and the merge behaves the way you'd expect.

Comment: I can also confirm the book code works for me exactly as written.

Answer (score 2):

(Note I haven't looked up the book code, just your post)

First confirm the dtypes:

```
print ratings_df.dtypes
print movies_df.dtypes
```

If you find they're different types you could try (let's assume ratings_df.movie_id is object instead of int):

```
ratings_df.movie_id = ratings_df.movie_id.astype(int)
```

See if your merge now works.